# Creating an XML file with text elements containing line breaks and tabs in Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to put a java exception stack trace as a text element in an XML file. A stack trace has line breaks and a tab character in the beginning of most lines, so to display it properly, I need to show whitespace which I do by putting `white-space: pre` in the XSL file. However, in the XML file I get both the white space which belongs to the stack trace and extra indentation white space. This is what ends up in the XML file:

```
                <Comment>java.lang.Exception: foo
            at ...
            at ...
            at ...
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fee
            at ...
        </Comment>
```

All lines except the first start with 8 extra spaces when I display the XML (the last 4 spaces of the 'at' lines are the tab character). Can I change how the XML is generated or displayed to show the stack trace properly?

Code excerpts:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.newDocument();
...
Element comment = doc.createElement("Comment");
comment.setTextContent(stacktrace);
```

XSL excerpt (the "Description" here is the same element as the "Comment" above):

```
                                <div class="GROUP">
                                    <table class="GROUP"
                                        style="width: 100%; table-layout: auto; white-space: pre">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="RESULT">Id</td>
                                            <td class="RESULT">Result</td>
                                            <td class="RESULT">Description</td>
```

Comment: Either add an `xml:space="preserve"` attribute to the element that holds the text or put your text into CDATA nodes (e.g. `<![CDATA[Text goes here]]>`).

Comment: You might need to create your own solution. If you run the generated XML string thru a "pretty print" function, your text nodes will most likely normalize. What have you tried?

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the question at first - your problem is not the displaying of the whitespace, but that extra whitespace is added by either your XML generator or some pretty printing function? How exactly do you apply the XSL, using xslt?

Comment: @ThomasBehr Neither solution seemed to do anything. In both cases, if I also included `white-space: pre` all white space was shown, and otherwise none was shown.

Comment: @l4mpi I don't know. There's a report.xml, a report.xsl and a style.css. I open the xml in firefox. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @H.v.M. You wrote: "However, in the XML file I get both the white space which belongs to the stack trace and extra indentation white space." and "All lines except the first start with 8 extra spaces when I display the XML." If you *manually* remove the 8 spaces of extra indentation white space from your XML file, does your stacktrace display correctly?

Comment: @ThomasBehr Yes.

Comment: @H.v.M. So, to solve your problem you need to change how your XML is generated to prevent the XML writer to add those extra indentation white spaces. How that can be achieved depends on how you write your XML. I don't mean the code to build the XML document, but the code to write the document to a file. And which version of Java do you use for that?

Comment: @ThomasBehr I'm on Java 17.

Comment: @H.v.M. Ok, fine. And how do you write that XML file? I don't know if it is still possible to edit your original question, but if it is, do that. Much easier to read formatted code.